# Python scp copy images from image_urls to server

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, urllib, scp

I have written one function which recieves a url and copy it to all server.
Server remote path is stored in db.

```
def copy_image_to_server(image_url):

  server_list = ServerData.objects.values_list('remote_path', flat=True).filter(active=1)
  file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen(image_url).read())
  image_file = Image.open(file)
  image_file.seek(0)

  for remote_path in server_list:
    os.system("scp -i ~/.ssh/haptik  %s %s " % (image_file, remote_path))
```

I am geeting this error at last line  `cannot open PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile: No such file`

Please suggest me what's wrong in the code, i have checked url is not broken

Comment: good first place to start debugging it would be to print out the command you are sending to scp and then try to run it in console. if it doesn't work, fix it there and then port back to python code.

Comment: Its printing this line `scp -i ~/.ssh/key <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=231x218 at 0x7FC8A6EFF200> ubuntu@ip:/home/ubuntu/test/.`

Comment: And that isn't clue enough for you about what is wrong there? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `image_file` is not a path (string), it's an object.  Your `os.system` call is building up a string that expects a path.

You need to write the file to disk (perhaps using the [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) module) before you can pass it to `scp` in this manner.

In fact, there's no need for you (at least in what you're doing in the code snippet) to convert it to a PIL `Image` object at all, you can just write it to disk once you've retrieved it, and then pass it to `scp` to move it:

```
file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen(image_url).read())
diskfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
diskfile.write(file.getvalue())
path = diskfile.name
diskfile.close()
for remote_path in server_list:
    os.system("scp -i ~/.ssh/haptik  %s %s " % (path, remote_path))
```

You should delete the file after you're done using it.